# Timegap on heroku servers

Tags: heroku

I have a strange issue with the scheduler.

I'm sending a reporting that's always referring to the last day, however the reporting always refers to the day before that day. E.g. on the 2nd of January (time of writing this), it's the 31th of december (it has nothing to do with month / year change).

When I log in to the server, the times seem to be correct:

```
$  date
Do 2. Jan 08:33:48 UTC 2014

# via python:
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 8, 33, 44, 650541)

# the func that calcs the previous day gives the correct day as well
>>> dates.getBeginningOfYesterday().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
'01.01.2014'
```

So, basically I'm not able to reproduce the error, but the scheduler keeps sending with this timegap.

Comment: Does datetime.now(utc) returns correct datetime?

Comment: Yes: `>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 11, 58, 5, 434947)`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is a local time offset causing you to span a day boundary incorrectly.  The examples you show are in UTC, but if you're using a localized timestamp for calculations there could easily be a `5+ hour` time offset, causing you to be a day earlier.

Comment: That was my inital guess, but I'm UTC+1 and the offset is larger than 8 hours.